# Cypher query for nodes related to other nodes where ALL other nodes appears in a given collection

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a domain based on the notion of things that are tagged that is modeled something like:

```
(item:Item)-[:TAGGED_BY]->(itemTag:Tag)
```

This is my first experiment with Cypher and am having trouble coming up with a query for items that are tagged by ALL of some given tags. For example:

```
CREATE
(item1:Item { name:"Item1"}),
(item2:Item { name:"Item2"}),
(item3:Item { name:"Item3"}),
(item4:Item { name:"Item4"}),
(item5:Item { name:"Item5"}),
(tag1:Tag { text: "T1" }),
(tag2:Tag { text: "T2" }),
(tag3:Tag { text: "T3" }),
(tag4:Tag { text: "T4" }),
item1-[:TAGGED_BY]->tag1,
item1-[:TAGGED_BY]->tag2,
item1-[:TAGGED_BY]->tag3,
item2-[:TAGGED_BY]->tag1,
item3-[:TAGGED_BY]->tag2,
item3-[:TAGGED_BY]->tag3,
item4-[:TAGGED_BY]->tag3;
```

I can find items that are tagged by either "T1" or "T2" a number of different ways (returning item1, item2, item3), but can't seem to come up with a query for all items that are tagged by BOTH "T1" and "T2" (returning just item1).

Any help would be appreciated - thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do:

```
MATCH (n:Item)-[:TAGGED_BY]->(t:Tag)
WHERE t.text IN ['T1','T2','T3','T4']
WITH n, count(*) as tags
WHERE tags = 4
RETURN n
```

with parameters

```
MATCH (n:Item)-[:TAGGED_BY]->(t:Tag)
WHERE t.text IN {tags}
WITH n, count(*) as tags
WHERE tags = length({tags})
RETURN n
```

Comment: I accepted the answer by Ankit Ladhania earlier because it is technically correct but then accepted this one because it is a bit more flexible and the answer I ultimately used in my code. I am liking neo4j and Cypher more with each passing day.

Answer (score 1):

The query you are looking for is this

```
MATCH (n:Item)-[:TAGGED_BY]->(Tag{text:"T2"}) 
WITH n 
MATCH (n)-[:TAGGED_BY]->(Tag{text:"T2"}) 
RETURN n;
```

Comment: Thank you so much - It makes perfect sense now that I see it! As a follow-on, what if the two tag nodes, [T1,T2] were the result of an upstream match rather than a given collection of literals?